# Wallet.rs Python binding - API concurrent requests

Tags: iota-network, wallet, python

I am having some issues while managing wallet.rs python binding with an API.
Is possible to manage the wallet with concurrent requests for several users at the same time?

I noticed this error when trying to make multiple requests at near the same time:

```
"data": "error accessing storage: IO error: While lock file: /usr/src/django/storage/account/db/LOCK: Resource temporarily unavailable",
```

It this possible and if it is what's the best approach to concurrently scale a system to manage the wallet.rs for several clients at the same time through a web service?